# Accessing DOM inside popup.Is this possible if the pages are on different servers?

Tags: javascript, popup

Hey I am trying to open a popup in a page and access the DOM in the opened popup from JavaScript in opener page. However I was unable to do so.

I am doing

```
myWindow=window.open(url,'','width=200,height=100');
```

then trying to access body of the popup as

```
myWindow.document.body
```

I am getting undefined for that.

Note the popup being opened is in another server from the opener page.

Is it me doing something wrong or is it impossible to do so?

Comment: If the pop up is in a different domain, the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents you from reading the page. If you control both pages, you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) in the browsers that support it. That means you would have to write code on both sides to communicate with each other.

Comment: No, you cannot execute javascript across domains, as it violates the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: It can only be done if the popup html that is being loaded from different server is on a sub-domain of your site. Which I guess is not your case.

Comment: Yes i guess now that its not possible.Thanks for the comments :)